# Python telegram bot celery start conflict

Tags: python, celery, python-telegram-bot, celerybeat

I have a very simple telegram bot and want to send an automated message to my bot users every 1 hour for example.
The problem Is that when I run `celery -A main worker --loglevel=WARNING -B` scheduled tasks is not running but when I remove `telegram_bot.runpolling()` it works exactly as it expected. Any idea how I can fix this issue?

```
import os
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, ContextTypes

print("Starting App")
from reminders import get_reminder, add_reminder

from celery import Celery
from time import sleep

app = Celery('main', broker='redis://localhost')


@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    # Calls test('printer') every 10 seconds.
    sender.add_periodic_task(10.0, printer.s(), name='add every 10')

@app.task
def printer():
        print("Celery Task Scheduler")


async def add_task(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
        add_reminder.add_for_day(' '.join(update.message.text.split()[1:-1]), update.message.text.split()[-1])
        await update.message.reply_text("Task Added")

telegram_app = ApplicationBuilder().token(os.environ['TOKEN']).build()

telegram_app.add_handler(CommandHandler("add", add_task))

#telegram_app.run_polling()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Application.run_polling`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a2/telegram.ext.application.html#telegram.ext.Application.run_polling) is designed mostly for the cases where you don't have any other components besides `python-telegram-bot` in your program. It uses [`asyncio.loop.run_forever()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_forever) which is probably why `celery` doesn't get a chance to do anything.

If you want to combine PTB with `celery`, you can probably try to substitute `run_polling` with a custom combination of `Application.{initialize, start, stop, shutdown}` and `telegram_app.updater.{initialize, start_polling, stop, shutdown` (see the docs of `run_polling` and the methods linked therein for more info, maybe also the source code of `run_polling`).

An alternative could be to use PTBs built-in [`JobQueue`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue) for scheduling the tasks instead of `celery`.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.